# VPN as a temporary layer of security?

Tags: web-application, vpn, web-service, django

I have a startup working on Django app, that will be processing sensitive personal and financial information. We're just finalizing a prototype of the product (no paying clients, no investors), so we're under-staffed on a limited budget.

Our product is a B2B tool, the first users of the prototype will be just a few employees in 2 companies. As a temporary security measure, I am considering setting up a VPN for them and making the production servers inaccessible to the public, but it's not that easy to set up correctly, so I'm questioning if this makes sense.

The app is not open for registration (invite-only) - there are only two public forms - log in and forgot password. Maybe I'm over-doing it with the VPN...

1. Is deploying behind VPN for extra security a good idea? It seems hard to set up, configure correctly & maintain, so is this a good practice?
2. Is there a checklist or some process I could go through, to make me more confident that a Django app is secure?

Comment: Why do you want to use a VPN? What protection does it give you?